# VBA: Click Save Button on Website

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I found a lot of similar problems but no solution for mine.
I navigate with VBA (Excel) in Internet Explorer. My code fills in some boxes and then clicks on the download button. Now, the dialog box appears with "Open", "Save" and "Cancel". My question is: How to select "Save As" with VBA? After starting my sub, I don't want to make any further clicks manually.

Many thanks.

```
Sub getcsv()
Dim i As Long
Dim URL, sCurrency As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim HWNDSrc As Long
Dim wbksdr As Workbook
Dim sdestpath As String

Set wbksdr = ThisWorkbook

sdestpath = "xxx\test.csv"

sCurrency = "USD"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
URL = "https://rtdata.dtcc.com/gtr/inquiry.do"
IE.Navigate URL
Do While IE.readystate = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until IE.readystate = 4: DoEvents: Loop

Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"

HWNDSrc = IE.HWND
SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc


IE.Document.getelementbyid("dailySearch_assetClassification").Value = "IR"
IE.Document.getelementbyid("dailySearch_notionalRangeLow").Value = 100
IE.Document.getelementbyid("dailySearch_notionalRangeHigh").Value = 5000000000#
IE.Document.getelementbyid("dailySearch_currency").Value = sCurrency
IE.Document.All("dailySearch_displayType_c").SetAttribute ("checked")
IE.Document.getelementbyid("dailySearch_SearchButton").Click


Application.Wait Now + #12:00:03 AM#
Application.SendKeys "%{S}"

Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#

IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: which vba are you referring to? excel or word or powerpoint???

Comment: With Excel.....

Comment: Application.GetSaveAsFilename. Does this work?

Comment: With this one, I have to manually accept. This means I have to click on "Save"

Comment: ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "Url of Path to save to"

Comment: This only save the workbook which contains the makro which I execute. It does not saves/downloades the file from the website.

Comment: For the moment, I solved it with send keys. But if there is a better technique, i would be happy use it.
Thank you for your help, Keenlearner.

Comment: Please edit the question, add code you have, post webpage URL and screenshot.

Comment: I edited my text. The URL is inlcuded.